# Why doesnt crontab execute my node script?

Tags: node.js, macos, cron

I wrote a node script that i want to execute every day using crontab.

Was looking for a way to find out what root crontab has
or how to navigate to my script
but could figure it out..

- - - - - /usr/local/bin/node &&  usrname/desktop/scriptname.js

If the execution works i should get a mail every minute

Comment: I don't think you need the `&&`. If you leave it as `/usr/local/bin/node usrname/desktop/scriptname.js`, it should work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You can also directly use node module --> https://www.npmjs.com/package/cron within your script to do the cron job.

This sample script executes every second.

```
var CronJob = require('cron').CronJob;
new CronJob('* * * * * *', function() {
  console.log('You will see this message every second');
}, null, true, 'America/Los_Angeles');
```

Comment: any chance you now how to start cronjobs on mac regardless if it is on or not?